# Window doesn't stay in a position (Precise, Classic)

Tags: 12.04, window, gnome-classic

Although I've started to see this phenomenon after I upgraded my notebook from `Oneiric` to `Precise`, I'm not sure what is influencing.
(1st one of the following image) I dragged the window on right to the bottom. Then while I move around cursor, (2nd image) the window moves back to the top rim.

[image]

[image]

In this example the one on left remains at the bottom for some reason. And this can happen to other application window (e.g. Firefox, System Monitor etc.) Any idea??

(Environment) NVIDIA Driver version: 295.40, `Gnome` Classic (when using `Ubuntu` as a desktop style, this issue didn't occur)

Comment: In fact at some point, I stopped seeing this without doing anything in particular though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having the exact same problem, it appears to be a Compiz issue.  Not sure how to fix it and still run compiz, but switching to metacity was a good solution for me:

Press Alt+F2 to open Run, and type in

metacity --replace

Answer (score 3):

You can work around this by disabling "place windows" feature in "ccsm".
first: sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
then launch: ccsm

This comes with a cost - windows are getting spawned under the top bar, but it's  a good workaround.

Comment: Disabling the "place windows" plugin is the only way that I found to make compiz still "usable". This is major pain because windows are now placed always under the task bar for me. Compiz under Ubuntu 12.04 has a lot of regression issues.

Comment: 12.04 is much crappier than 10.04 for me... this is a significant part of the problem.